# how can i return the result from function in android

Tags: java, android

I want to encapsulate the AlertDialog into a function so that i can make my code more readable and clutter free. But i am unable to make this function to return the result

```
public int ShowMessageBox(Context context, String title, String  message){
     int result;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(title.toString())
            .setMessage(message.toString())
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    result = 1; //error here
                    //dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    result = 2; //error here
                    //dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .show();
    return result;
}
```

How could i return the result so i can use this function as

```
int i = ShowMessageBox(MainActivity.this, "Title", "Message");
if (i == 1)
   do this
 else if (i == 2)
    do that
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is async and you should keep it like that. You can make an `Interface` and pass it into your method. This'd be your Interface:

```
public interface MessageBoxListener {
    void result(int result);
}
```

Your updated method:

```
public void showMessageBox(Context context, String title, String  message, final MessageBoxListener listener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle(title.toString())
        .setMessage(message.toString())
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                listener.result(1);
                //dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                listener.result(2);
                //dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .show();
}
```

To use it, you'd do something like this:

```
showMessageBox(MainActivity.this, "Title", "Message", new MessageBoxListener() {
    @Override
    public void result(int result) {
        if (result == 1) 
            // Do something
        else
            // Do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you. worked well with little changes, like final messageboxListener listener and MainActivity.this instead of this.